# ¿Cómo mostrar el logo de mi web cuando pego su dirección en las redes sociales?

Tags: php, seo

Quiero que se me muestre el logo cuando pego mi web en las redes sociales u en otra parte.

[image: imagen de ejemplo]

Utilizo esto para mostrar la imagen:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.superatucrisis.com.ve/logo/logo supera tu crisis.png"/>
```

Sin embargo, no muestra nada pese a que la ruta de la imagen está bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pon lo siguiente:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.superatucrisis.com.ve/logo/logo-supera-tu-crisis.jpg"/>
```

La imagen en png, cámbiala por jpg.

Yo he probado y me funciona.

Comment: ok amigo ya lo corrige ahora esperar que se actualice a ver si ese era el detalle

Comment: no la muestra amigo

Comment: Prueba lo del jpg que te explico arriba

Comment: gracias me funciono me quedo asi `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.superatucrisis.com.ve/logo/stc.jpg"/>`